# WPJOBMANAGER, send email to application email on Job listing approval

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am using WP Job manager and I want to send an email to on the application email once the job listing has been approved by the admin. I have found this code https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-send-email-employer-job-listing-approved/ but this only works to send a notification email to a user that already has an account.  I want to send an email to the email provided in the job listing as often those users do not have an account on our website.  I am sorry if this question has already been answered, I have looked around and couldn't find one. Also I tried to tag this with WPJOBMANAGER but I don't have enough rep to create a tag.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after doing a bunch of research I have managed to find a way to do this.

```
function listing_published_send_email($post_id) {

    if( 'job_listing' != get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $job = get_the_job_application_method($post);

    // Message to be sent to users.
    $message = "Put the message you want to send here";

    // Checks to see if the person who submitted the job listing is a user or a guest.
    if ($author == 0 OR $author == NULL){

        // Checks to see if the email is valid.
        if ($job->type == 'email') {
            $email = $job->email;
            wp_mail($email, "Your job listing is online", $message);
        }
        else { // The email is not valid so return.
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        wp_mail($author->user_email, "Your job listing is online", $message);
    }
}
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'listing_published_send_email');
add_action('pending_payment_to_publish', 'listing_published_send_email');
```

Should just be able to put this code in functions.php file and it will work.